# Rails - How do display an integer in options_from_collection_for_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wish to display a list a selectable list of 1-42 on a form.  I have an array assignment in the controller's new me to create the list:

```
@cabinet_position_list = (1..42).to_a
```

The number will be assigbed to device.position but I can't figure out how to display the numbers in the box.  Here's the best I've come up with on the form:

```
<%= f.select :position, options_from_collection_for_select(@cabinet_position_list, "position", "?????") %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need options_from_collection_for_select in this case. Just:

```
f.select :position, @cabinet_position_list
```

or

```
f.select :position, (1..42).to_a
```

Comment: +1 as simple as that... PS: `to_a` is not necessary, just `f.select :position, (1..42)`

Comment: Thanks Babur and gabrielhilal!

Answer (score 0):

`options_for_select(@cabinet_position_list)` should work !